# Swift .sorted(by:) returns the incorrect type

Tags: arrays, json, swift, sorting

I have an array of type [String: MyCustomStruct] that's being decoded from a response by the server. I'm then just trying to sort the array on the client side based on a value in the custom struct. For some reason, I'm getting an error:

```
'Cannot assign value of type '[Dictionary<String, MyCustomStruct>.Element]' (aka 'Array<(key: String, value: MyCustomStruct)>') to type '[String : MyCustomStruct]''
```

My code looks like this:

```
do {
    decodedArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: MyCustomStruct].self, from: jsonData)
    print("DECODING PROCESS SUCCESS: \(decodedArray)")
} catch {
    print("DECODING PROCESS FAILED: \(error)")
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.places = decodedArray.sorted(by: { $0.value.rating > $1.value.rating })
}
```

Why is this getting a type error? The type of 'self.places' is also defined as [String: MyCustomStruct]...

Comment: I guess your return type should be ```[(String, MyCustomStruct)]```.

Declaration: ```var places: [(String, MyCustomStruct)]```

Answer (score 1):

`[String: MyCustomStruct]` is not an Array. It's a Dictionary. That is very important here. You're not decoding an Array.  Sorting a Dictionary probably does not mean what you expect. The `Dictionary.sorted(by:)` function returns an Array of Elements, which is what you're seeing here.

I expect `self.places` is of the wrong type. It should be `[MyCustomStruct]` given the code you've written. If you're trying to create an ordered dictionary, see [OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md) in the swift-collections package.